# Authentication with web based flutter app

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, browser-security

I want to build a flutter app where people can log in and post things for other users to see. I want this app to be accessible in a browser and thought I could use Flutter-Web.

I can run the flutter app on a server with a local database but the issue is that if one user accesses the page and logs in, then everybody else is also logged in as that user.

The only solution I can see is if everybody would download my flutter app to their local machine, start an instance and then all those instances communicate with a remote database.

I can use a remote database, although I don't like it, but I don't want people to install anything.

Is there a way around by serving multiple flutter instances, one for each browser session?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The library [flutter-auth-ui](https://github.com/polina-c/flutter-auth-ui) provides UI for Firebase authentication.

See how it works [here](https://flatter-auth-ui-demo2.codemagic.app/#/).